# Pointer to the Address of Element of an Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, addressof

```
int s[4][2]= {
             {1234,56},
             {1212,33},
             {1434,80},
             {1312,78}
             };
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",*(s[i]+j));
    }
}
```

Output Showing is

> ```
> 1234,56
> 1212,33
> 1434,80
> 1312,78
> ```

As we know `*(&Variable)` will print the Value of the Variable But when We implement the same concept in above program...

```
int s[4][2]= {
             {1234,56},
             {1212,33},
             {1434,80},
             {1312,78}
             };
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",*(&s[i]+j));
    }
}
```

output is showing the Address of each element of array.

Why this is happening? 
Why Output is not equal to value of elements of Array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is bi-dimensional. So, `s[i]` is the address of line `i` (i.e. `s[i]` is of type `int *`), and `&s[i]` is an address of an address (i.e. of type `int **`). When you apply `*` on it, you get an address (i.e. `int *`).

It is true that the operator `&` means "address-of" and `*(&x)` refers to the value of `x`.

Comment: Thanks I think It is accurate for the Question asked

Comment: "s[i] is of type int *" NO. `s[i]` is of type `int [2]`, an array type, which can be implicitly converted to `int *` in certain contexts. "and &s[i] is an address of an address (i.e. of type int **)" NO. `&s[i]` is of type `int (*)[2]`, a pointer-to-array type. "When you apply * on it, you get an address (i.e. int *)" Again, no. You get `int [2]`, which can be implicitly converted to `int *` in certain contexts.

Comment: @newacct LOL. ok. But I prefer saying things simply (but not %100 accurate) for a beginner to understand easily rather than saying accurate yet complex answers. Also, this distinction between `int [2]` and `int *` is somehow "logical", and IMHO, not worth mentioning in the answer of this question, as @Kunal talks about addresses in his question.

Comment: @newacct You can see that the answer satisfied the PO more than "real accurate" answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Notice here**, `s` is a two dimensional array, and array names decay to pointer to the first element, in certain cases.

Here, `s[i]` is of type array, array of two `int`s.

Then, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1,

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

Thus,

- In the first case,

  ```
  *(s[i]+j)
  ```

  `s[i]` is of type `int [2]`, which decays to an `int *`, which is used in the pointer arithmetic, producing another `int *`. After the dereference, you get an `int`.
- In the second case,

  ```
  *(&s[i]+j)
  ```

  due to the same aforesaid reason, in case of `&s[i]`, `s[i]` does not *decay*, and the type is "pointer to `int [2]`" and the pointer arithmetic works on that. So, in this case, the result of the addition is also "pointer to `int [2]`" and after the final dereference, it becomes `int *`, which is the mismatch for `%d` and that is what reported by your compiler.

Comment: Thanks Fro explaining

Answer (score 0):

**First case**

Your print statement is this.

```
printf("%d  ",*(s[i]+j));
```

Here s[i]+j is the address.

lets consider i=0,j=1 , first i loop, second j loop.

here s[i] will be the address in which value 1234 is residing. lets say it is 489000.
so s[i]+j , here s[0]+1 will be the address at which value 56 is residing. lets say it is 489004

So, *(s[i]+j) ,ie; here *(s[0]+1) will be giving the value at address 489004. ie 56.
So here it will print the values 1234, 56, 1212 etc.

**Second Case**
Your print statement is this.

```
printf("%d  ",*(&s[i]+j));
```

Here &s[i]+j is the address.

lets consider i=0,j=0 , first i loop, first j loop.

here s[i] will be the address in which value 1234 is residing.
Lets say it is 489000.
So &s[i] will be the address in which address 489000 is residing.
Lets say it is 380000.
Recall the concepts of pointer's.

So &s[i]+j will be "address in which address 489000 is residing + j" .
ie; 380000+j

we are applying a value at operator * on this particular 'address' we got.
*(&s[i]+j).
So it becomes, 
Value at['address in which address 489000 is residing' + j].
Value at[380000 + j].

when i=0,j=0, it will print,  Value At[380000] , ie; 489000.

So it will print the address in which the values 1234, 56 , 1212 etc are stored.

Comment: @Kunal Verma : Hope this will be usefull.

Comment: @Kunal Verma : You are welcome. Please up vote the answer if you got the concepts clear, so that others can also check this. Thank you.